# Record RAM and Processor Usage per user (individual users usage)

Tags: powershell

I am using windows server 2016 and in my server there are multiple users login remotely in same time, and each user consumes RAM and processor resources of server i want to record each user usage in csv file with date and time, i am using this script and getting results for only RAM usage for individual users, result csv file is showing all users usage per application,  i want to  sort users and calculate ram usage of all users also want to record processor usage. Please help.

This is my PowerShell Script.

```
#Get WMI Process objects
$WMIProcs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process
#Get Get-Process object
$GPProcs = Get-Process
#Convert Get-Process objects to a hashtable for easy lookup
$GPHT = @{}
$GPProcs | ForEach-Object {$GPHT.Add($_.ID.ToString(),$_)}
#Add PrivateWorkingSet and UserID to WMI objects
$WMIProcs|ForEach-Object{ 
    $_ | Add-Member "Mem Usage(MB)" $([math]::round($GPHT[$_.ProcessId.ToString()].PrivateMemorySize64/1mb,2))
    $_ | Add-Member "UserID" $($_.getowner().Domain+"\"+$_.getowner().user)
}
#Output to CSV File
$WMIProcs | Select-Object ProcessName, "Mem Usage(MB)", UserID | export-csv -Path C:\users\abc\Music\ram.csv
```

This is my out results in csv file

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject
"ProcessName","Mem Usage(MB)","UserID"
"System Idle Process","0","\"
"System","0.13","\"
"smss.exe","0.38","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
"chrome.exe","76.77","abc\Administrator"
"chrome.exe","1.92","abc\Administrator"
"chrome.exe","17.88","abc\Administrator"
"chrome.exe","12.38","abc\Administrator"
"chrome.exe","7.19","abc\Administrator"
"chrome.exe","44.55","abc\Administrator
"MFAUClient.exe","2.43","abc\bms"
"MFStatus.exe","4.64","abc\bms"
"kavtray.exe","2.19","abc\Administrator"
"kavtray.exe","2.19","abc\Administrator"
"kavtray.exe","2.19","abc\bms"
"AnyDesk.exe","32.36","abc\bms"
"acrotray.exe","1.29","abc\bms"
"jusched.exe","4.65","abc\bms"
"Lightshot.exe","2.58","abc\bms"
"csrss.exe","2.29","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
"winlogon.exe","1.86","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
"dwm.exe","24.73","Window Manager\DWM-7"
"CpDeploy.exe","58.37","abc\noccctv"
"rdpclip.exe","2.01","abc\noccctv"
"CpAccel.exe","44.72","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
"RuntimeBroker.exe","3.07","abc\noccctv"
"sihost.exe","5.21","abc\noccctv"
"svchost.exe","5","abc\noccctv"
```

While i need this output

Anyone Can Please Help

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject
"ProcessName","Mem Usage(MB)","UserID","Total Used Memory by user"
"chrome.exe","800.77","abc\Administrator"
"kavtray.exe","4.38","abc\Administrator","805.15"
"chrome.exe","544.55","abc\bms
"MFAUClient.exe","60.43","abc\bms","604.98"
```

Comment: You can see throughout your code the use of `Mem Usage(Mb)` why not look up the atribute for CPU, pop it in and see if it works

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks For Replaying Can you please share any example please

Answer (score 0):

Try using Group-Object:

```
#Get WMI Process objects
$WMIProcs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process
#Get Get-Process object
$GPProcs = Get-Process
#Convert Get-Process objects to a hashtable for easy lookup
$GPHT = @{}
$GPProcs | ForEach-Object {$GPHT.Add($_.ID.ToString(),$_)}
#Add PrivateWorkingSet and UserID to WMI objects
$WMIProcs|ForEach-Object{ 
    $_ | Add-Member "MemUsageMB" $([math]::round($GPHT[$_.ProcessId.ToString()].PrivateMemorySize64/1mb,2))
    $_ | Add-Member "UserID" $($_.getowner().Domain+"\"+$_.getowner().user)
}

$Results = $WMIProcs | Group-Object UserId | ForEach-Object {
    # Group by UserID, so use the group name for UserID
    $UserID = $_.Name
    # Get total memory for this user
    $Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-Object MemUsageMB -Sum).Sum
    # Iterate through the group, outputting desired properties
    $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            UserID = [string]$UserID
            ProcessName = $_.ProcessName
            "MemUsage(MB)" = $_.MemUsageMB
            TotalMem = ''
        }
    }
    # Output an identical object, with different fields for the Total
    [pscustomobject]@{
        UserID = [string]$UserID
        ProcessName = 'Total Memory Use'
        "MemUsage(MB)" = ''
        TotalMem = $Sum
    }
}
# Output stored in $Results, export as required
$Results | Out-GridView
```

Comment: -scepticalist thanks from your suggesion i am getting user id details group wise but memory usage  tab and totalMem tab is blank!!! kindly check your suggested script is there any thing is missing please comment i will be very thank full to you thanks again

Comment: Look closely and you'll see you just need a small edit to your script - see above

Comment: -Scepticalist brother thanks thankyou so much it works for me thank you so much :)